# Routing table export

Tags: networking

Want to export routing table off Checkpoint VSX firewall and import it into VmWare NSX.

How to export routing table from Checkpoint VSX?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

1 Depending on the target version of gateway, you may need to upgrade your management. Note that all new appliances only support R77.30 and above. If you're running a lower version of code on your management, you will need to do that first.

2 Stage the new gateway OS in the lab (configure networking, routes needed, etc). Depending on whether or not the new gateway will assume the IP addresses of an existing gateway, you may or may not necessarily establish SIC with the management at this point, but at least establish the one-time password so the gateway is ready when the time comes.

3 Create a combined policy that includes all the appropriate rules from all the gateways that are being replaced. While you can certainly copy/paste all the rules, you should take the opportunity to review the rules in detail to see what rules are actually needed or not as well as put some thought into the order of rules. You should use the "Verify Policy" option in SmartConsole/SmartDashboard to make sure there are no obvious mistakes.

4 Develop a plan for doing the actual cutover, accounting for the cables that need to be swapped, routes that need to be changed, ARP caches that may need to be flushed, etc. Make sure you have a backout plan in case things go sideways. 
During the actual cutover will probably be the time you establish SIC and push policy to the device.

I'm probably missing a few minor steps above, but it should be a good starting point.

I strongly encourage engaging the services of a local partner or Check Point Professional Services to assist with this task

Comment: Wasn't the question about the _routing table_? Your answer doesn't even mention it, beyond "routes needed" in step 2.  I seem to remember from my Checkpoint on Nokia days that routing configuration wasn't even part of what Checkpoint and its management software cared or knew about...

Comment: Indeed. This is what routing protocols are for. (if you have the appropriate checkpoint license) I just dump the output of `ip route print` and go from there. [hint: it's a linux box.]

Comment: Jonathan if I can call you that. Thanks for the knowledge, though Ricky did provide the answer that I was looking for. Will incorporate with the rest of the project. Guys again thanks so much.